# Рандомный выбор данных из нескольких столбцов .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа, csv

Мне необходимо прочитать csv файл и выбрать рандомно из каждого перечисленного столбца с индексом 1,2,3 и т.д. значение.

Шел по такому пути:

```
import random
import csv

    with open(file_csv) as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        data_category=[row_c[1] for row_c in reader]
        data_prize=[row_p[2] for row_p in reader]
    category=random.choice(data_category)
    prize=random.choice(data_prize)
```

Но конечно получаю ошибку Cannot choose from an empty sequence

Для одного столбца работает и я получаю случайное значение

```
import random
import csv
    with open(file_csv) as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        data_category=[row[1] for row in reader]
    category=random.choice(data_category)
```

Не понимаю, как сделать выборку для нескольких столбцов...

Прихожу к такому варианту

```
import random
import csv

    with open(file_csv) as f:
        incl_col = [1, 2, 3]
        reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
        data_category=[row[1] for row in reader]

        for row in reader:
            col = list(row[i] for i in incl_col)
            category=random.choice(incl_col)
```

Но не понимаю, как в переменную присвоить значение рандомного выбора для каждой колонки...

Помогите, пожалуйста, советом
Спасибо

Comment: Почему бы вам не воспользоваться `pandas`?

Comment: "`Но не понимаю, как в переменную присвоить значение рандомного выбора для каждой колонки`" – то есть, сохранить все полученные случайные выборы?

Comment: @AivanF, да, именно так

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно просто сохранить выбранные значения, то создайте какую-нибудь [коллекцию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), например, переменную со списком для накопления значений:

```py
import random
import csv


    selected_categories = []

    with open(file_csv) as f:
        incl_col = [1, 2, 3]
        reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
        data_category=[row[1] for row in reader]

        for row in reader:
            col = list(row[i] for i in incl_col)
            category = random.choice(incl_col)
            selected_categories.append(category)

    print('Selected categories:', selected_categories)
```

Comment: AivanF, полученные значения из каждого столбца я присваиваю переменные и вставляю в другой запрос

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для этого `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sss.csv") # примерный csv
```

Получаем таблицу:

```
    John    Doe 120 jefferson st.   Riverside   NJ  08075
0   Jack    McGinnis    220 hobo Av.    Phila   PA  9119
1   John "Da Man"   Repici  120 Jefferson St.   Riverside   NJ  8075
2   Stephen Tyler   7452 Terrace "At the Plaza" road    SomeTown    SD  91234
3   NaN Blankman    NaN SomeTown    SD  298
4   Joan "the bone", Anne   Jet 9th, at Terrace plc Desert City CO  123
```

берем сампл:

```
df.sample()
```

Получаем:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5
1   Jack    McGinnis    220 hobo Av.    Phila   PA  9119
```

Или, если нужно несколько:

```
df.sample(3)
```

Получаем:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5
2   John "Da Man"   Repici  120 Jefferson St.   Riverside   NJ  8075
3   Stephen Tyler   7452 Terrace "At the Plaza" road    SomeTown    SD  91234
0   John    Doe 120 jefferson st.   Riverside   NJ  8075
```

Comment: Спасибо. с помощью pandas получилось это решить -> iloc использовал для вывода данных по одному полю